# Computer won't boot if any drive connected to PS (SATA cable not connected) but USB drive okay, GTX 1080 video card okay

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, hardware-failure

Weird problem.  Computer is new-ish, been working fine for months.  Yesterday afternoon it suddenly died.  Try to boot it, the lights in the case light up for 0.1 second and have to power off/power on PS to try again.  I pulled memory, video card, swapped power supplies, and finally found one thing that can create or resolve the problem: disconnecting or connecting any drive to the PS, all of this with no SATA cables connected.  Just the mere fact that a drive (tried two 3.5" HDDs and also a CD ROM drive) is connected causes the computer to refuse to power up.  I added everything else back, the NVidia GTX 1080 card, other fans, memory, same situation if a drive is connected to the PS the computer will refuse to power up (beyond 0.1 seconds).  I made a bootable USB stick and it boots into Linux Live fine, everything works, video, networking, etc.

I tested with two PSs, so it can't be the PS.  I tested multiple HD power cables, so it can't be them.  I tried with multiple drives (some of which hadn't been in the computer before) so it can't be the drives.  It happens whether the video card is in or out so it can't be the video card.  I don't see how it can be the CPU if Live Linux works perfectly.  Happens whatever memory stick was in (tried swapping memory), so can't be that.  The only thing that seems left is the motherboard, but how could it be the motherboard if it can run Live Linux fine?

The symptom of instantly powering off makes me think something is trying to draw too much power and the MB or PS gives up and shuts down.  Something is either shorting or simply drawing too much power.  But wouldn't a video card draw more power than a hard drive or CD ROM drive, and it would still instantly shut off when there was no video card and just one drive.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I've seen fans do something similar.  Try unplugging them all and re-adding them 1 by 1 to see if that's the issue.  This includes the CPU and GPU fans.  Just be ready to turn it off quickly of the CPU or GPU is the cause.  As this is a WAG, I'm not putting it into an answer, unless it happens to be correct.

Comment: Good suggestion.  Sadly just tried it, unplugged every fan in turn and same behavior with HD power cable connected.

Comment: Have you looked for any blown capacitors or other damaged components?  How about any possibly metallic/conductive debris on the mobo?  I know this sounds basic, but I've seen veteran (10+ year) computer techs fail to do this check.

Comment: This will probably sound odd, but have you checked that everything is grounded correctly?  Based on what you're saying, it sounds like _something_ is shorting a power rail to ground, and that is ultimately causing an overcurrent condition to shut down the PSU.  Maybe try changing out the case and see if everything works?

Comment: All good thoughts.  I just inspected the motherboard pretty closely and everything looks perfect, it's just under three months old and zero dust or anything to obscure my inspection. All caps look healthy, no shorting, burning, no burnt smell anywhere obvious.  As for grounding/etc. I'll pull the motherboard tomorrow, in desperation I ordered an identical one to swap.  Hope it's the mobo at this point or I'll feel pretty stupid.